# How can I build the German subordinate clause properly?

Tags: sentence-structure, word-order, subordinate-clause

> 1. Jeder ist dafür, was sie gesagt haben, verantwortlich.
> 2. Jeder ist für das, was sie gesagt haben, verantwortlich.
> 3. Jeder ist dafür verantwortlich, was sie gesagt haben.

Which one is correct? Can the *Nebensatz* be put in the middle of the main clause?

Answer (score 4):

All three sentences are correct. However, you should note that the sentences now mean that each member of a group represents the statements of an entire group.

If you want to say that every person is responsible for his own statements you need to say

> Jeder ist für das, was er sagt, verantwortlich

This is (in my opinion) gender neutral. The hardcore gender fanatics would stone me and instead say something like

> Jede(r) ist für das, was er/sie sagt, verantwortlich

Or any of the other form's you've provided in your question.

Answer (score 3):

2 und 3 sind korrekt von der Satzstellung her. 1 klingt nach meinem Sprachgefühl komisch.

Man muss statt "sie" aber "er" verwenden ("Jede**r** ist dafür verantwortlich, was **er** gesagt hat"). Wenn die Gruppe nur aus Frauen besteht, kannst Du "Jed**e**…, was **sie** gesagt hat" benutzen.

Außerdem ist "jede(r)" Singular, also muss es "gesagt hat" statt "gesagt haben" heißen. Um den Plural zu behalten, könntest man sagen "Alle sind für das verantwortlich, was sie gesagt haben" (bzw. "Alle sind für das, was sie gesagt haben, verantwortlich").

Comment: Vielleicht geht es darum, dass jeder einzelne für die Äußerung einer Gruppe verantwortlich ist.